# Protobuf: extension registry issue

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use kind-of-inheritance in protobuf, which is implemented via extensions mechanism. The problem is that I have to pass an additional parameter to serializer/deserializer to make it work properly:

```
ExtensionRegistry registry = ExtensionRegistry.newInstance();
Animals.registerAllExtensions(registry);
Zoo newZoo = Zoo.parseFrom(buf, registry);
```

Another problem is that I am using 3rd-party library (RPC) which has protobuf built-in, so I have no control over serialization/deserialization in the code.

Is there a way to register extensions globally?

P.S. Protofile for my question:

```
message Zoo {
  repeated Animal animals = 1;
}

message Animal
{
    extensions 100 to max;

    enum Type
    {
        Cat = 1;
        Dog = 2;
    }

    required Type type = 1;
}

message Cat
{
    extend Animal
    {
        required Cat animal = 100; // Unique Animal extension number
    }

    // These fields can use the full number range.
    optional bool declawed = 1;
}

message Dog
{
    extend Animal
    {
        required Dog animal = 101; // Unique Animal extension number
    }

    // These fields can use the full number range.
    optional uint32 bones_buried = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to register extensions globally.  Your RPC library should allow you to specify an `ExtensionRegistry` -- if it doesn't, that's a serious problem in the library.  You can work around it by serializing the message object you receive and then re-parsing it with an `ExtensionRegistry`, although this of course wastes CPU time.

**Editorial:**  The reason extensions cannot be registered globally is that global registries tend to lead to lots of subtle problems.  They are essentially singletons, and are bad for all the usual reasons that [singletons are bad](http://www.object-oriented-security.org/lets-argue/singletons).  Essentially, code can become unexpectedly dependent on implementation details of unrelated pieces of code in the same process, harming modularity and reusability.  For example, some code in a server might unintentionally rely on some other, unrelated piece of code to register an extension for them, and then when that other piece of code changes or is removed, the first piece of code unexpectedly breaks in a weird, subtle way -- suddenly it appears as if the desired extension is never present in incoming messages.  The protobuf C++ library actually has a global extension registry, and we saw lots of problems of this sort in practice, so between that and the fact that Java classes have no way to force some code to run "at startup" (static initialization happens lazily, which makes it harder to ensure that registration happens at the right time), I decided it was best to avoid a global registry altogether.  Of course, this decision has its own problems as you've seen...  it seems there is no correct answer here.  :(